# KOTLIN : Pull data from Firebase with listview representation

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list view in a fragment. I controlled as array list these items in the list view. Then I showed in my Fragment. Now, I am trying to connect to database. I can add data to firebase database.
My REALTIME DATABASE like this. I want to pull title from here.

```
+news
|---+23a56e25-ffd6-4780-9b39-56b745076454
    |---+description: 
    |       "sasasasa"
    |---+title: 
            "title1"
```

And in Firebase STORAGE, there are images under news folder like "news>idOfmyImage"

My model is here.

```
public class NewsModel(Title: String, Image:Int)  {

    val title:String
    var image:Int

    init {
        title = Title
        image = Image
    }

}
```

HERE IS MY FRAGMENT. I was add to list and use it for listview. How can I pull data(image+text) from firebase database and add to my list ? I appreciate for your support.

```
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
      val v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false)
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        databaseReference = database?.getReference()!!.child("news/title")
        storage = Firebase.storage.reference
        var list: ArrayList<NewsModel> = arrayListOf()

       var imageref = Firebase.storage.reference.child("news/")
        imageref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
            Uri ->
                val imageURL = Uri.toString()
               var imagesquare = (R.id.iv_homepage) as ImageView


                Glide.with(this)
                        .load(imageURL)
                        .into(imagesquare)
        }

      /*  var m1 = NewsModel("Title1", R.drawable.foto)
        var m2 = NewsModel("Title2",R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal)
        var m3 = NewsModel("Title3", R.drawable.foto)
        list.add(m1);
        list.add(m2);
        list.add(m3);
*/
        val adapter = Adapter(requireActivity(), list)
        v.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.list_view).adapter = adapter
       addnews_button= v.findViewById<Button>(R.id.addnews_button)
        addnews_button.setOnClickListener {
            var intent = Intent(activity, AddNews::class.java)
            activity?.startActivity(intent)
        }
        return v
    }
```

Comment: I can also share my adapter page if you want

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo There are no errors but not pull data from firebase database